# XML file code format issue in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, layout

After updating Android Studio to 3.5 when I Press Ctrl+Alt+L to format Layout XML file code, it changes sequence of the controllers.

Before Pressing Ctrl+Alt+L

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="Position 1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="Position 2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

After Pressging Ctrl+Alt+L

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Position 2" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Position 1" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Sequence of button and textview changed. 
Couldn't found any solution for this.